# Weak convergence in Bochner space where Banach space is finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the separable Banach space $V$, and let it be finite-dimensional.

Let us now consider the measure space $T$ and consider $L^2(T;V)$.
It is known that weak and strong convergence of a sequence in $V$ are equivalent if $V$ is finite-dimensional.
Does the same hold in the Banach space $L^2(T;V)$? My guess is that it does not, but I struggle to find a counterexample.

I have also tried to prove it using that $L^2(T;V)^*=L^2(T;V^*)$ and tried to use that we can write every element in $\xi \in V^*$ as $\xi = \xi_i e^{i}$, so... we should be able to say that

$$
<\xi,u>=\int_T <\xi(t),u(t) > \mathrm{d}\mu=\int_T <\xi_i(t)e^i,u^j(t)e_ j>\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_T \xi_i(t) u^i(t) \mathrm{d} t,
$$
so if we pick $\xi(t)=e^i$ we will have that $e^i(u(t))=u^i$, and then we should be able to proceed with the standard proof... but this feels... probably not right? I think the problem lies in assuming that I can write an element in the dual of $V$ like I do. Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Not if $T$ is arbitrary.

For example if $T=\{ 1,\ldots,n\}$ with the counting measure and $V=\mathbb{R}$, then $L^2(T,V)$ is simply $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean norm; so in this case it's actually true.

On the other hand if $T=\{ 1,2,\ldots, n,\ldots\}$, and $V=\mathbb{R}$, then $L^2(T,V)=\ell^2$ is the space of square summable sequences, i.e. x$=(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^2$ if and only if
$$
\| x\|_{\ell^2}^2:= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_i|^2 <\infty.
$$
The sequence of elements $e^j\in \ell^2$ given by
$$
e^j:=(0,\ldots, 0,1,0,\ldots),
$$
where the lone $1$ is in the $j$-th position, satisfies that $e^j\to 0$ weakly but not strongly.

More generally, whenever $L^2(T;V)$ is inifinite dimensional you'll be able to construct counterexamples simply by taking a countable orthonormal set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good examples. I guess $[a,b]$ will not work then, for instance?

Comment: @ejk: No, for $T=[a,b]$ (with Lebesgue measure) and $V$ any nontrivial Banach space, $L^2(T;V)$ will be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Minor aside: If $V$ is not a Hilbert space, strictly speaking there are no orthonormal sets in $L^2(T;V)$. But of course the statement is still true because $L^2(T;V)$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. This means that $L^2(T;V)$ is infinite-dimensional if and only if $V$ is non-trivial and $L^2(T)$ is infinite-dimensional.